# Netbeans fails to deploy to GlassFish and and Tomcat on Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

my environment, all local, is as follows: Linux (Fedora 22), Netbeans 8.0.2, jdk1.7.0_79, GlassFish 4.1,Tomcat 8.0.9.0. Netbeans + GlassFish + Tomcat were installed as official Nebeans bundle, through its installer. Netbeans and both app servers are installed in /usr/local by the root user. Just in case, i did chmod -R 777 on all 3 folders, hence ensuring full rwx access for any user. Netbeans is started by a regular user, which just in case is put to the 'root' group to ensure access.

The issue is that Netbeans fails to deploy my projects to either GlassFish or Tomcat. When, after rebooting Linux,  i try to run a project in Netbeans (which includes build + deploy) for the first time, the build part is fine, then the IDE attempts to start GlassFish (or Tomcat) and never recognizes it as being started, with no clue present in the logs (just with some messages in the log which appear normal). Subsequently, project deploy from Netbeans consistently fails. However, GlassFish (or Tomcat) gets in fact started by Netbeans (nothing else starts it) and is up and running seemingly ok. I'm able to deploy the corresponding WAR to it manually, through the admin web application. To exclude possible issues with my own project, i recreated the issue using a demo project which comes with Nebeans, to same effect. My research of various web resources on this topic didn't bring any fruit so far. Tried many things, including re-installing Netbeans and even astarting over with a fresh Linux box - same result. Will appreciate any help i can get, please!